# SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio workflow breakpoint not hit

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, workflow, sharepoint-2013

I'm using VS 2013 and a SP 2013 farm solution which contains a workflow.
I'm desperately trying to debug my workflow to gain some inside information.

**This is what I tried so far:**

- First of all I set a breakpoint on a **GetCurrentItemId** Activity
- Next I hit **F5**.
- The workflow test host console opens up and the web browser showing my sharepoint site
- Next I navigate to my list and start the workflow on any (single) item
- The workflow test console stays all black - not a single piece of information to find here
- The workflow's internal status changes to "Completed".

***...obviously my breakpoint has not been hit. WHY? :(***

---

#### Solved

Reinstalling VS 2013 did in fact help.

Comment: VS2013? How is it going? So far all my workflow development has been on VS2012.

Comment: It's beyond my understanding why it didn't work in the first place. After reinstalling VS 2013 it worked like a charm. No workflow related isues anymore.

Comment: No, my question was if VS2013 is better than VS2012 for workflow dev?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you have been starting your workflow in debug mode and trying to debug in on a list event.

Instead of doing that try adding your breakpoints (I always add breakpoint in the first scope) and then go to
**Debug** -> **Attach to Process** and look for **Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe** and click attach.

Before doing any work with that list items to trigger the workflow verify that your breakpoints are active - if not try retracting your solution and redeploy, then one more time try attaching it to the WF service.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach to the process Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe you must select the type of code you will attach to. Just select Workflow and you´ll be able to see the workflow context variables.